# How to compare values of two different hash maps in python

Tags: python, hashtable

Hi i'm trying to figure out how to compare the values of two different hash maps that I have.

```
hash1 = {'animals':['dogs','cats']}
hash2 = {'canine': ['dogs','wolves']}
```

From the example above, since the key canine in hash2 has a value 'dogs' matching with the key animals in hash1 which also has 'dogs', I want it to print out 'canine'.

I was able to do something like this when a key only have one value, but I need it to have a long list of values and if any of the values match, I want it to print out which key it had any matches with.

EDIT: 
I want it to print out 'canine' because for example if I had multiple keys in hash2

```
hash2 = {'canine':['dogs','wolves'],'domestic':['horse','rabbit']}
```

I would only want it to print out 'canine' because that's the one that matches, instead of printing out the entire hash2

EDIT 2:
    hash1 = {'animals':['dogs','cats']}
    hash2 = {'canine': ['dogs','wolves']}

```
for value in hash2.values():
    if value in hash1.values():
        #not sure how to write this so here's pseudocode
        print(hash2[key of matching value])
```

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear. You should provide a better example or more details. Why is 'canine' being printed out and not 'animals'? What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 3.6

Comment: Oh I read your question wrong. It doesn't really matter which one prints out, whether it's 'animals' or 'canine'. I just keep receiving a KeyError whenever I try to compare the values.

Comment: Please, post your code

Comment: For the record, hash maps are called dictionaries or `dict`s in python.

Answer (score 1):

We can build a `set` that contains all the items from all the values of `hash1`. We can then check if there is any intersection between that set and each of the values of `hash2`.

```
from itertools import chain

hash1 = {'animals':['dogs','cats']}
hash2 = {'canine':['dogs','wolves'],'domestic':['horse','rabbit']}

hash1_values = set(chain.from_iterable(hash1.values())) 
# equivalent to set(x for it in hash1.values() for x in it)


for k, v in hash2.items():
    if any(item in hash1_values for item in v):
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that I think will get you close to what you are looking for. Let me know if it helps.

```
hash1 = {'animals':['dogs','cats']}
hash2 = {'canine':['dogs','wolves'],'domestic':['horse','rabbit']}

for key, value in hash1.items():
    for key1, value1 in hash2.items():
        matches = set(value).intersection(set(value1))
        if matches:
            print(matches)
            print(key, key1)
```

Comment: Please mark this as answered to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
for key_1,value_1 in hash1.items():
    for key_2,value_2 in hash2.items():
        if len([x for x in value_1 if x in value_2])>0:
            print(key_2)
```